# Fonts used in an old french article

Tags: fonts

I was wondering if anybody knows how to get fonts similar to the ones used by Jean-Pierre Serre in the article “FAC” (as on the picture).

I can’t find a way and it drives me mad !

I hope you’ll be more successful/ inspired than I am doing so.[image]
Thanks in advance :)

Max

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Monotype Modern, on which Computer Modern is based. Also MlModern is available, with somewhat heavier strokes.

The boldface is a bit different, though.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

%\usepackage{mlmodern} % uncomment for the second picture

\addtolength{\textwidth}{-0.5cm}
\calclayout

\begin{document}

\title{Faisceaux algébriques cohérents}
\author{Jean-Pierre Serre}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

On sait que les méthodes cohomologiques, et particulièrement la théorie
des faisceaux, jouent un rôle croissant, non seulement en théorie des
fonctions de plusieurs variables complexes (cf.~[5]), mais aussi en
géométrie algébrique classique (qu'il me suffise de citer les travaux
récents de Kodaira-Spencer sur le théorème de Riemann-Roch).
Le caractère algébrique de ces méthodes lassait penser qu'il était
possible de les appliquer également à la géométrie algébrique abstraite;
le but du présent mémoire est de montrer que tel est bien le cas.

\end{document}
```

#### Output with Computer Modern (actually European Modern)

[image]

#### Output with MlModern

[image]

Comment: awesome thanks !